# Css reset: font-size: 100%; Why?

Tags: css, reset

I am studying the css reset of S. Meyer, found here: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

My question is: what is the purpose of: font-size: 100%?

Can somebody explain it?

Comment: I've heard that IE has some scaling issues sometimes and that font-size:100%; fixes this issue.

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?636866-what-s-the-point-of-font-size-100-on-body-doesn-t-seem-to-make-any-difference

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It "Sets the font-size to a percent of  the parent element's font size". Therefor if the parent is 14px the child would be 14px based on the setting. It is a way to allow for dynamic resizing of fonts.

Answer (score 4):

Titles such as H1, H2 etc by default have different font sizes. This rule resets them to what the browser considers the default text size.

Answer (score 1):

Necroposting because I just came across this thread while working with an older codebase.

The 100% reset was put in place to work around bugs in Internet Explorer 6 and 7.    IE6 was shipped in 2001, and IE7 was shipped in 2006.

It's probably safe to delete this line if it's causing you issues.